# Do we support Ubuntu on Termux?

Tags: discussion, scope

[Termux](https://termux.com/) is an Android terminal emulator and Linux environment app. Termux's wiki contains [instructions to install Ubuntu](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Ubuntu) on top of their Android app. 
I don't think it is a standalone distribution or official derivative of Ubuntu. Do we support questions specific to Ubuntu on Termux?

Since [Termux's app page on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=en_US) suggests users to ask questions on [termux - reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/termux/), should we ask users to go there closing their questions here on Ask Ubuntu as off-topic?

Comment: Is it fair to these users to close their questions and send them off to a different website? Perhaps there are still users here that can answer Termux Ubuntu questions, even though it's not an *official* version of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dev If we want to adhere to the rules and topicality of the site, yes, it's fair to ask them to post on some other site, for example, [unix.se].

Comment: Related: https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19577/are-the-official-ubuntu-base-images-for-arm-on-topic-in-ask-ubuntu?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- It is not an officially endorsed OS. Like for instance WSL is.
- They point to reddit themself already making a point stating AU is not the place.

So I would say: no, we do not.

There is also [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/termux) to send them to.

Comment: What about [android.se]?

Comment: @Kulfy Android.SE mod here. We accept questions regarding the operation of Termux including installing Ubuntu on Termux, but we can't support the operation on Ubuntu part because Ubuntu is not Android.

Comment: @AndrewT. That makes sense. Thanks for the info.