# Are the official Ubuntu Base images for ARM on topic in Ask Ubuntu?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, android

Canonical hosts [Ubuntu Base images](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-base/releases/20.04/release/) for ARM and other architectures. These are minimal root file system images. After installing them, one can install desktop environments and use GUI with VNC on the same phone. It is possible to play sound too.

Do we support them on this site?

In case we support them, then our official stance regarding using [Ubuntu on Termux](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/19077/do-we-support-ubuntu-on-termux) may have to change, because these images can be run in [Termux](https://termux.com/) with [PRoot](https://proot-me.github.io/).

These images can be installed in almost any Android device (even on 5+ years old discarded Android phones), and have a lot of possibilities (which will only increase in near future) with the so many (recently released) `libhandy`-based, touch-friendly applications.

### These images really come handy

For example, I was able to install [Foliate](https://github.com/johnfactotum/foliate/issues/690) eBook reader and the ambient noise app [Blanket](https://github.com/rafaelmardojai/blanket/discussions/114) on my Android phone, and almost all their features work.

[image: Foliate]

<sup>*[Foliate eBook reader](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2020/06/foliate-ebook-search-comic-support) running on my `armhf` Android phone, with an Ubuntu 20.04 base image in Termux.*</sup>

**In case we don't support them currently, let's have a discussion if we can support them from now onwards.** Since Ubuntu-on-Android was discontinued, and Canonical shifted its focus from Ubuntu Touch, this is the next best Ubuntu experience we can have on Android phones and tablets.

Comment: In case they are on topic, I would be happy to answer questions regarding solving common issues, many of which I have figured out by trial and error.

Comment: I don't see anything in Ask Ubuntu Help that says questions concerning arm are off-topic. Ubuntu Base is basically just minimal minimal. whether arm or amd. I will ask a question, lets see what happens.

Comment: Is running Ubuntu in Termux any different than running it in Vbox? Question posted: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1332171/how-can-i-install-foliate-ebook-reader-on-my-android-phone-using-ubuntu-base +1

Comment: Might depend on whether the problem is about Ubuntu on termux or termux on android....

Comment: So, same rules as with VBox?

Comment: There are some differences with virtualbox. The OS in Termux shares the Linux kernel with Android.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be running Ubuntu in a container of some sort. The parts inside the container would be on-topic, just like, say, a Ubuntu Docker or LXC container would be, and to some extend the parts interfacing with the containerization (e.g., networking config inside Ubuntu), but I don't see why the parts outside it would be, which would include the containerization itself or the configuration thereof.

If you have, for example, trouble with:

- touch not working properly, that's the problem of whatever VNC client Termux has, and not an Ubuntu issue.
- GUI theming, that would be a problem entirely within the Ubuntu installation unrelated to the containerization used.